# Is there a way to insert a vertex with a user defined image icon from a local folder ? (Jgraphx)

Tags: java, imageicon, vertex, jgraphx, jgraph

I want to use a user defined icon as vertex. 
It works if the png file is saved in the resource folder, however i want to get the png file from a local folder

Actions.directory.toString() - folder location as String - working

the vertex appears without any shape

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(Actions.directory.toString() + "/" + Actions.hm.get(key)));  

icon = new ImageIcon(img);  
System.out.println("icon " +icon);  

mxStylesheet stylesheet1 =  ShowGraphEditor.graph.getStylesheet();  
Hashtable<String, Object> attributestyle = new Hashtable<String, Object>();  
attributestyle.put(mxConstants.STYLE_SHAPE, mxConstants.SHAPE_IMAGE);  
attributestyle.put(mxConstants.STYLE_IMAGE, getClass().getResource(Actions.directory.toString() + "/" + Actions.hm.get(key)) );  
attributestyle.put(mxConstants.STYLE_VERTICAL_LABEL_POSITION, mxConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);  

stylesheet1.putCellStyle(eventName, attributestyle);  

GraphMenu.getGraph().insertVertex(null, instance.getID().toString(), instance, GraphMenu.x,GraphMenu.y, 80, 30, eventName);
```

**I've tried:**

`attributestyle.put(mxConstants.STYLE_IMAGE, icon)`

Comment: Is there any exception or log generated for this problem?

Comment: @DushyantTankariya  no. there is now exception or log generated. the vertex appears but without shape

Comment: If there is no log or Exception then you need to debug the code line by line and verify the statement `mxConstants.STYLE_IMAGE, icon` that it stores icon or not in attributestyle. If not which means the Image/shape/icon is not loaded yet to java and it's not able to put on your attributestyle.

Comment: @DushyantTankariya the icon is loaded, i can use it to load and show it ion my GUI palette. Just inserting as vertex isnt working

Comment: Refer the [link](https://forum.jgraph.com/vote/4783/down/index.html) and verify with your code if you are missing something.

Comment: @DushyantTankariya  i know this link. i did it exactly how it is described. And i dont want to store the image in the project.

Comment: Have you update your graph after adding icon `GraphMenu.getGraph().getModel().endUpdate();`

Comment: yes @DushyantTankariya